# Google maps crashes in every screen that containing map ('int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference)

Tags: android

Suddenly Google maps crashes in every screen that containing map which cause app crash.

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 56854
Process: com.interface_fze.dawana.pharmacy, PID: 3151
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214815081@21.48.15 (150400-0):11)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214815081@21.48.15 (150400-0):3)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.g.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214815081@21.48.15 (150400-0):18)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214815081@21.48.15 (150400-0):14)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.av.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214815081@21.48.15 (150400-0):44)
```

Comment: Do you find any solution ?

Comment: Yes, it is mentioned in the below answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed issue by adding `implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.3.0'` in app level build.gradle

[Source](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/219879780?pli=1)

Answer (score 2):

Removing app/clearing cache fixed issue for me.

Comment: This actually fixes my issue, I am wondering if this issue will show up in production.